# What is the meaning of Logos?

Tags: fallacies, theology

While trying to ascertain a better understanding on the topic of [Logos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos), I interpret from a offering a more modern view that it is "*a logic that recycles God into a mind hiding through sign-manifestations of itself*"[2](https://www.mqup.ca/half-brain-fables-and-figs-in-paradise-products-9780773523555.php).

I wonder if someone could further explain to me this passage and the meaning of Logos.

Comment: i don't understand the quote at all :(

Comment: Are you referring to the use of logos in John 1?

Comment: Logos is Word. The Unmanifest first manifests Itself through Word, as we cannot think or express ourselves without words. It (God), the unconditioned, first becomes conditioned through Word.

Comment: The Rational Priority Principle asserts that Logos, or Reason, lies outside the circle of the world (though only in a formal and not an ontological sense). The Epistemological Principle asserts that knowing what comes before (via the Logos) yields "control" of what comes after.https://princeofnothing.fandom.com/wiki/D%C3%BBnyain

Comment: Logos regulates orders of existence in both the universe and human reason.

Comment: Logos is the most universal among all things in the world, an intermediary between the transcendent God and the created world. God created the world with logos as the intermediate being.https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Logos

Comment: In Being and Time/ Heidegger described logos as prelanguage, a preliminary perception of the world which often finds expression in verbal communication. https://philpapers.org/rec/WARLIH

Comment: logos is the path to Being. Language precedes man and is the "house of Being." By this Heidegger means that man lives in language which is the major force in the creation of his world. https://philpapers.org/rec/WARLIH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bible commentator, David Pawson, describes the use of *logos* from [John 1:1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_1:1) as "the reason why". (page 553)

> [Heraclitus] used the word *logos* to stand for 'the reason why', **the purpose behind what took place**. When he looked at life (*bios*) he looked for the *logos*; when he studied the weather (*meteor*) he sought the *logos*. This concept now appears in our words for the study of different areas in science: biology, meteorology, geology, psychology, sociology, etc.

Pawson then claims that John did something similar:

> John, realizing that **Jesus is the ultimate reason 'why' everything happened**, took up this idea and called Jesus the logos, 'the Word'. The whole universe was made for him. He was the Logos before there was anyone else to communicate with. That is the reason why we are here. It is all going to be summed up in him. He is the 'Reason Why'.

Based on the above, one theistic interpretation of "Logos" as a description of Jesus is "the reason why".

---

Pawson, D. Unlocking the Bible. (2007) HarperCollins and True Potential Publishing.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!